# 405 (Method Not Allowed) (POST) method with ajax jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, http-status-code-405

im trying to send some data through ajax jQuery to a php file with POST but i keep getting POST 405 Method Not Allowed error, any ideas to solve this issue will be appreciated, heres the function that makes the call

```
function manageData(key) {
    var name = $("#countryName");
    var abbrev = $("#countryAbbrev");
    var desc = $("#countryDesc");

    if (isNotEmpty(name) && isNotEmpty(abbrev) && isNotEmpty(desc)) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/ajax.php',
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'text',
            data: {
                key: key,
                name: name.val(),
                abbrev: abbrev.val(),
                desc: desc.val()
            },
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and here is the ajax.php file code

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['key'])) {

        $conn = new mysqli(host:'localhost', username:'root', passwd:'root', 
        dbname:'mysqldatamanager');
        $name = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
        $abbrev = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['abbrev']);
        $desc = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['desc']);

        if($_POST['key'] == 'addNew') {
            $sql = $conn->query(query:"SELECT id FROM country WHERE 
            countryName = '$name'");
            if ($sql->num_rows > 0) {
                exit("Country already exists!");
            } else {
                $conn->query("INSERT INTO country (countryName,                     
                countryAbbrev, countryDesc) VALUES ('$name', '$abbrev', 
                '$desc')");
                exit("Country has been added succesfully!");
            }   
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: if you are working in localhost?. Please comment your project folder location.

Comment: Nothing in that PHP is going to return a 405 error. You probably need to look at your server configuration to allow POST requests. (Also: Make sure it is the POST request that is getting the 405 and not a preflight OPTIONS request).

Comment: @Quentin: How do I know if the POST is getting 405 error or a preflight OPTIONS request? And in case of the latter, what do I need to do to get rid of the error? I'm new in jQuery AJAX and facing the same problem. Please help.

Comment: The Network tab of the browser's developer tools will show you the verb and response code.

Answer (score -2):

Please try below code.

```
function manageData(key) {
    var name = $("#countryName");
    var abbrev = $("#countryAbbrev");
    var desc = $("#countryDesc");

    if (isNotEmpty(name) && isNotEmpty(abbrev) && isNotEmpty(desc)) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/ajax.php',
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                key: key,
                name: name.val(),
                abbrev: abbrev.val(),
                desc: desc.val()
            },
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: If they were not posting a value of `key` (and the source code in the question shows that they are), then the result would be skipping over the chunk of PHP that is in the question, **not** returning a 405 error.